# Replacing text strings

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have a markup file with lots of text like so:

```
My markup file <title value="The title" /> and more text
and another title <title value="XXX" />The <text> blah blah blah
```

How do I replace all these all the titles with a new title (probably using regular expressions)? A couple of rules first:

1. The values between the title quotes are different.
2. There are other `value="xxxxx"` text not related to titles.

Thanks!

Comment: If you're file is an XML (or HTML), use a proper parser to parse and replace.

Comment: It's a psuedo markup so its not pure XML

Comment: any instances of `<title someotherAttrib="something" value="The title">` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think this should do it:

```
string output = Regex.Replace(txt,"<title value=\".*?\"","<title value=\"My new title\"");
```

Edit: If your title tags ever have extra arguments, this will replace them too, but leave extra arguments intact:

```
string output2 = Regex.Replace(txt, "<title(.*?)value=\".*?\"", "<title$1value=\"My new title\"");
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the various values you will have as *The Title*...you could use a text editor that supports regex find and replace like notepad++ with:

```
<title value="[A-Za-z ]*" />
```

as your regex.  If your titles have more than just numeric characters and spaces you would need to alter the *[A-Za-Z ]*

Answer (score 0):

If you which to replace some text inside double quotes, you can do something like this:

```
string originalStr = "My markup file <title value=\"The title\" /> and more text and another title <title value=\"XXX\" />The <text> blah blah blah";

string replacedStr = Regex.Replace(originalStr, @"""[^""]+""", "\"NewText\"");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Named Capturing Groups](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/30wbz966.aspx#the_captured_group) and [Substitutions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewy2t5e0.aspx) to achieve this like below:

```
public static string ReplaceTitle(string input, string newTitle)
{
    string findPattern = @"(?<prepend><title\s+value\s*=\s*\"")([^\""]*)(?<append>\"")";
    string replacePattern = "${prepend}" + newTitle + "${append}";

    return Regex.Replace(input, findPattern, replacePattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
}
```

And here is a demo code that tests the above case

```
using System.IO;
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string input = "My markup file <title value=\"The title\" /> and more text and another title <title value=\"XXX\" />The <text> blah blah blah";

        Console.WriteLine(ReplaceTitle(input, "NEWTITLE"));        
    }

    public static string ReplaceTitle(string input, string newTitle)
    {
        string findPattern = @"(?<prepend><title\s+value\s*=\s*\"")([^\""]*)(?<append>\"")";
        string replacePattern = "${prepend}" + newTitle + "${append}";

        return Regex.Replace(input, findPattern, replacePattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    }
}
```

Comment: Unrecognized Escape Sequence. Try `string findPattern = @"(?<prepend><title\\s+value\\s*=\\s*\"")([^\""]*)(?<append>\"")";`

Comment: np, it's still a little off, now that it's got the @ \" is a string delimiter so you need \""

Comment: Now it should work. Thanks!